# Typescript: How do you create a general type for functions with arguments and return types extending from a specific type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have these classes and these types:

```
type Values = string | number | boolean | ...

type Func<Arg extends Values, Ret extends Values> = (arg: Arg) => Ret



class Parent<Arg extends Values = ???, Ret extends Values = ???> {
    constructor(public validateFunc: Func<Arg, Ret>) {}
}

class ChildString extends Parent<string, string> {}

class ChildNumber extends Parent<number, number> {}

...

// note that a child class may also extend from Parent where Arg and Ret is different, say:
class ChildHybrid extends Parent<string, number> {}
```

Now, I want to assign a child to a variable typed using its parent, but this does not work because you cannot assign `(arg: string) => string` to `(arg: Values) => Values`:

```
const unknownChild: Parent = new ChildString(arg => arg) // error
```

**What would be the values of ???, and if it is impossible, how do i restructure my code? Using `any` is prohibited.**

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wga4lm) what you're looking for?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't usable, `unknownChild.validateFunc`'s `arg` is typed as `never` and thus `arg` can't be assigned to anything.

Comment: `never` is the correct type so if you can't use it then you have to refactor.  You'd need `Parent<A, R>` to be generic always; you cannot say `const unknownChild: Parent = ...` because there is no concrete `Parent` type you'd accept.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wyjpxw) work for you instead?

Comment: Yes this works, please write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll do so when I get a chance. Might not be for a few hours.

Comment: Oh by the way, tell me how you'd refactor this

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I was saying you can't write `const x: Parent =` because there is no specific `Parent` type that works and you'd need to refactor to use generic types everywhere and associated helper functions to infer.  The refactoring was as I showed in my link from above.  It's not a big refactoring for the few lines in your example but it could be much larger if you had to find every reference to `Parent` without generics and replace it with generics.  Does that make sense and address the followup question? If so I'll write up the answer as planned, otherwise can you elaborate?